# Modifying CDbCriteria to look at my pivot table

Tags: sql, yii, frameworks

I have three tables - myusers, organisation_classrooms, organisation_classrooms_myusers (this is a pivot table between organisation_classrooms & the myusers table)

organisation_classrooms(classroom_id, organisation_id, title)
organisation_classrooms_myusers(classroom_id, user_id)
myusers(user_id, organisation_id, fullname)

I have the following search() function within one of my models:

```
return new CActiveDataProvider(OrganisationClassroom::model()->currentUserOrganisation(), array(
     'criteria' => $criteria,
     'pagination' => array(
     'pageSize' => 10,
     )
 ));
```

This is the dataset that I am using

```
organisation_classrooms
classroom_id     title      organisation_id     
  1          Class A         37383
  2          Class B         37383
  3          Class C         37383


organisation_classrooms_myusers
classroom_id     user_id
  2            1558
  3            1558

myusers
user_id    organisation_id   name
1558          37383       Bob Doe
```

I'd like to amend the model so that for each organisation_classroom that belongs to the organisation, check if the user_id 1558 exists in the organisation_classrooms_myusers pivot table and basically set a boolean value

e.g

I'd like the following data returned via the organisation_classrooms CActiveDataProvider used above for the user_id of 1558

```
classroom_id    title     organisation_id   pivot_set
      1        Class A         37383            0
      2        Class B         37383            1
      3        Class C         37383            1
```

Can anyone suggest how to go about this? Alternatively if anyone can demonstrate a raw SQL query that will produce this result that would be very useful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on another website which got me in the right direction - if it helps someone else:

```
// CDbCriteria $criteria already prepared given other search criteria, then: */
   $criteria->select = 't.classroom_id, t.title, t.organisation_id, case when cu.classroom_id is null then 0 else 1 end as pivot_set';
   $criteria->join = 'left join organisation_classrooms_myusers cu on cu.classroom_id=t.classroom_id and cu.user_id=:uid';
   $criteria->params['uid'] = $uid;  /* e.g. 1558 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Add column "id" (primaryKey) in "organisation_classrooms_myusers".

```
SELECT room.classroom_id,room.title,room.organisation_id, if(rela.user_id,1,0) AS pivot_set FROM `organisation_classrooms` AS room LEFT JOIN organisation_classrooms_myusers AS rela ON rela.classroom_id = room.classroom_id
```